# A Terminal error occurs when running rqt_remocon in Ubuntu terminal for ROS

Tags: ros, rqt

I was trying to follow the ROS tutorial below to get rqt_remocon to work on my laptop:
http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot/Tutorials/indigo/A%20First%20Interaction

I get the following command as an output:

```
[debug] Interactive Client : initialised
[debug] Interactive Client : Connection Details
[debug] Interactive Client :   Node Name: rqt_remocon_d38f3fdd429e48fda747cf757ed43a46
[debug] Interactive Client :   ROS_MASTER_URI: http://localhost:11311
[debug] Interactive Client :   ROS_HOSTNAME: 192.168.1.30
[debug] Interactive Client :   ROS_MASTER_PORT: 11311
[debug] Interactive Client : Get interactions service Handle
[error] InteractiveClientInterface : failed to find all of the interactions' publications and services for [get_interactions]
```

The last warning also pops up as a window.

Comment: which part of the tuto did throw that error ?

Comment: Running rqt_remocon